# How to use asio concurrent_channel with multiple signatures (& C++-20 coroutines)

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++20, boost-asio

So the `concurrent_channel` [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/channels.html) say:

> the set of messages supported by a channel is specified by its template parameters

That implies you can send more then one message type. (Right?)  The [concurrent_channel reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/experimental__basic_concurrent_channel.html) indicates `typename... Signatures` which looks like where you'd specify multiple argument-sets.

So starting with a working example, it seems to me you just add more Signatures, maybe like this:

```
using my_channel = channel<
        void(boost::system::error_code, std::size_t), // this alone, straight from the example, works.
        void(std::string, float) // adding this breaks it inscrutably
        >;
```

All my attempts at something like this end in an avalanche of compiler errors at the `async_receive()` and `async_send()` call sites (some making reference to `payload_type` which makes sense conceptually but I don't understand or see in the docs).

**Anyone have a working example of this, particularly that uses coroutines?**

(Caving and just passing a union/variant/any would bring shame to my ancestors. I realize, too, that I'm mixing `channel` and `concurrent_channel` but the same solution should work for both.)

**PS:** In my fiddling with channels, it seems that if you don't specify `error_code` as the first parameter, things break. Is that documented somewhere that I missed? Just `void()` seems to work too, as one example uses. Even more mysteriously, the [working example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp20/channels/throttling_proxy.cpp) sends an `error_code` but **knows not to receive it back**:

```
using token_channel = channel<void(boost::system::error_code, std::size_t)>;
...
co_await tokens.async_send(
    boost::system::error_code{}, bytes_per_token,
    use_awaitable);      
   ...
// How did they know not to expect error_code back?
std::size_t bytes_available = co_await tokens.async_receive(use_awaitable);
```

Comment: [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade I didn't feel like my wild guesses at `async_send()` / `async_receive()` constructions, that wouldn't even compile, would be helpful enough to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An underdocumented restriction is how error-propagation is deduced from the signature. The `use_awaitable` token translates these into exceptions. I may be wrong, but it seems that at least an error_code argument must be provided for that to work.

This is *not* mandatory if you use callback style, which you can check by doing a simple async receive:

```
chan.async_receive([](auto&&...) { std::cout << "DETECT\n" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; });
```

Which for your example will print something like: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd36bde3917d33b5)**

```
DETECT
main()::<lambda(auto:53&& ...)> [with auto:53 = {boost::system::error_code, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]
DETECT
main()::<lambda(auto:54&& ...)> [with auto:54 = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, float}]
```

> *Note that there seems to be QOI issues surrounding constructors of channel_message, compare: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20385fd813ee6ddd.*

A similar error novel arises when using another completion token with special treatment of errors:

```
auto x = chan.async_receive(asio::use_future);
```

In fact, one needs to disable concept support to make it pass the compiler:

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_CONCEPTS
```

And even then, the deduced type of `x` is `void`, instead of the expected `future<>` instance. The usual tricks `asio::as_tuple` and `asio::redirect_error` do not help: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8418ae75969257d2

All in all there's enough there to say that something is broken that was actually supposed to work. I noticed that none of the examples and none of the tests exercise the multiple-signature support. Consider reporting an issue with the simplest self-contained example distilled from this question: https://github.com/boostorg/asio/issues

### Workarounds?

Conceptually, I'd expect `co_await` to return a `variant<Tuple1, Tuple2>` where the tuple types are `tuple<error_code,string>` and `tuple<string, float>`. You can mimick this yourself by changing the signature to

```
void(variant<Tuple1, Tuple2>)
```

instead and doing the visitation outside of Asio's completion token mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent analysis! I wasn't aware of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` -- very helpful, since one aggravation is seeing a working callback `[](auto...){ }` but not being able to tell what's in the `auto...`.  Your [basic example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd36bde3917d33b5) has two identical `async_receive` lines!  How can you route payload types more deliberately than that?  Considering these issues, is this solid enough to use even with single-signature/variant?

Comment: The point is the signatures *are* different. It’s just that I was lazy to spell them out with a variadic lambda like that. You can always have `struct Handler { void operator()(error_code, std::string); void operator()(std::string, float); }` or do the equivalent with e.g. the [`overloads` trick](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/visiting-a-std-variant-with-the-overload-pattern/). I think it’s solid enough, but it’s “experimental”. That status mostly means that interface changes are likely to happen and indeed some kinks like the once we may be seeing here have to still be ironed out