# C++ / asio / coroutine consumer, threaded producer: is a correct solution possible with existing mechanisms?

Tags: c++, c++20, boost-asio, c++-coroutine

C++-20 with coroutines (co_await), with boost::asio. I'm implementing a producer/consumer relationship: the **consumer** runs in a co-routine, the **producer** fires from any other thread.  Using `std::queue` for transport.

If it were reversed with coroutine as producer, it's straightforward: my coroutine would do a `unique_lock`, push into the queue, release the lock, then call the `data_ready_condition.notify_one()`. Threads would use `data_ready_condition.wait()` with the mutex, `pop()` from the queue with the mutex locked on the way out of `wait()`, unlock the mutex, and be on our way. Classic thread synchronization.

Back to the original problem: the threaded producer does the classic lock/push/unlock, but now the thread would do a `data_ready_condition.notify_one()` ...  **but there seems to be no such async version of `std::condition_variable`** for the coroutine side, that would do this:

```
co_await data_ready_condition.async_wait(); // No such thing?
```

I can't find it, or anything truly equivalent, in the asio docs.  I thought I was being clever using `asio::steady_timer` and using `cancel()` in place of `notify_one()`.  But now I don't think this will cut it without the mutex really coordinated with it.

So is there a way to do a true `async_wait()` with either `std::condition_variable` or something that asio provides?  (It seems like `io_context` would supply this bridge somehow, since that's related to its job, but again I can't find it.)

Any other `std::` or 3rd-party library I should know about? The compiler itself provides `co_await`, right? But I don't see *anything* outside of asio designed to harness it.

What am I missing?

---

I'm using boost::asio 1.83, gcc version 13.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project), `-std=c++20 -fcoroutines`

Comment: What thread do you want the consumer to run on?

Comment: @NicolBolas Something like, which runs with other async tasks ("agents"), all non-blocking, in a single thread: `co_spawn(ioCtxt, MyConsumer(),  asio::detached);`

Comment: I don't see why you would want to wrap that in a coroutine at all. What you should have is a thread-safe queue that many things dump objects into (producers), and periodically a task (the consumer) comes along to extract things from the queue and process them. That's not really coroutine stuff.

Comment: That is, the consumer task doesn't benefit from anything `co_await` actually does here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using std::queue for transport.

`std::queue` is not a transport. It's a medium.

> I can't find it, or anything truly equivalent, in the asio docs

I think I can, see below

> I thought I was being clever using asio::steady_timer and using cancel() in place of notify_one().

Yes, this has been established pattern for about a (half) decade of Asio.
Note that there is is even `cancel_one` these days, so you can more usefully model condition variables.

> [...] But now I don't think this will cut it without the mutex really coordinated with it.

Somewhat true. You can get around the need for explicit synchronization (locking) by using [strands ("Strands: Use Threads Without Explicit Locking")](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html). However, if you really want to use non-asio threads you have no other option than to use tradional thread synchronization.

### Channels

Without further ado, let me suggest [Channels](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/channels.html).

> *Note: "experimental" means the interface might still change, but the concept is here to stay*

In your case you could use a `concurrent_channel` and consume it from many coroutines.

### Example

With a blocking (synchronous) producer thread:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f42391a9a5c904e)**

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

static inline auto out() {
    static constexpr auto now   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    static auto const     start = now();

    static std::atomic_int        tid_gen = 0;
    static thread_local int const tid     = tid_gen++;
    return std::osyncstream(std::clog)                    //
        << std::unitbuf << "th:" << std::setw(2) << tid   //
        << std::setw(8) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms " //
        ;
}

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/concurrent_channel.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

using boost::system::error_code;
using Message = std::string;
using Channel = asio::experimental::concurrent_channel<void(error_code, Message)>;
static auto const err_shutdown = asio::error::eof; // TODO use own error_code

asio::awaitable<void> delay(auto duration) {
    co_await asio::steady_timer(co_await asio::this_coro::executor, duration) //
        .async_wait(asio::deferred);
}

asio::awaitable<void> consumer(int id, Channel& chan) {
    out() << "Consumer " << id << " start" << std::endl;

    error_code ec;
    auto       token = redirect_error(asio::deferred, ec);

    for (; !ec.failed();) {
        Message msg = co_await chan.async_receive(token);
        if (!ec) {
            out() << "Consumer " << id << " handling " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;

            co_await delay(10ms); // simulate work
        }
    }

    if (ec == err_shutdown)
        chan.close(); // or cancel(), whatever makes sense for your application

    out() << "Consumer " << id << " leave (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

void producer(Channel& chan) {
    auto send = [&chan](unsigned n, auto text, error_code ec = {}) {
        while (n -= chan.try_send_n(n, ec, text)) {
            out() << "Producer waiting for queue space\n";
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
        }
    };
    out() << "Producer start" << std::endl;

    for (auto text : {"foo", "bar", "qux"})
        send(3, text);

    out() << "Producer signal system shutdown" << std::endl;
    send(1, "", asio::error::eof);

    out() << "Producer leave" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    out() << "Start" << std::endl;
    asio::thread_pool ioc;
    Channel           chan(ioc, 10);

    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        co_spawn(ioc, consumer(i, chan), asio::detached);

    producer(chan);

    ioc.join();
}
```

Typical outputs:

[image]

### BONUS: Async Producer

Note that synchronous producers may result in sub-optimal throughput ([Boost Asio experimental channel poor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73505015/boost-asio-experimental-channel-poor-performance/73596981#73596981)). Also, I think async producers are much more elegant:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb98fe3823c4bc50)**

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

static inline auto out() {
    static constexpr auto now   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    static auto const     start = now();

    static std::atomic_int        tid_gen = 0;
    static thread_local int const tid     = tid_gen++;
    return std::osyncstream(std::clog)                    //
        << std::unitbuf << "th:" << std::setw(2) << tid   //
        << std::setw(8) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms " //
        ;
}

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/concurrent_channel.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

using boost::system::error_code;
using Message = std::string;
using Channel = asio::experimental::concurrent_channel<void(error_code, Message)>;
static auto const err_shutdown = asio::error::eof; // TODO use own error_code

asio::awaitable<void> delay(auto duration) {
    co_await asio::steady_timer(co_await asio::this_coro::executor, duration) //
        .async_wait(asio::deferred);
}

asio::awaitable<void> consumer(int id, Channel& chan) {
    out() << "Consumer " << id << " start" << std::endl;

    error_code ec;
    auto       token = redirect_error(asio::deferred, ec);

    for (; !ec.failed();) {
        Message msg = co_await chan.async_receive(token);
        if (!ec) {
            out() << "Consumer " << id << " handling " << quoted(msg) << std::endl;

            co_await delay(10ms); // simulate work
        }
    }

    if (ec == err_shutdown)
        chan.close(); // or cancel(), whatever makes sense for your application

    out() << "Consumer " << id << " leave (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

asio::awaitable<void> producer(Channel& chan) {
    out() << "Producer start" << std::endl;

    for (auto text : {"foo", "bar", "qux"})
        for (auto n : {1, 2, 3})
            co_await chan.async_send({}, text + std::to_string(n), asio::deferred);

    out() << "Producer signal system shutdown" << std::endl;
    co_await chan.async_send(asio::error::eof,"", asio::deferred);

    out() << "Producer leave" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    out() << "Start" << std::endl;
    asio::thread_pool ioc;
    Channel           chan(ioc, 10);

    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        co_spawn(ioc, consumer(i, chan), asio::detached);

    co_spawn(ioc, producer(chan), asio::detached);

    ioc.join();
}
```

With very similar outputs:

```
th: 0       0ms Start
th: 1       0ms Consumer 0 start
th: 2       0ms Consumer 1 start
th: 4       0ms Consumer 2 start
th: 3       0ms Consumer 3 start
th: 3       0ms Consumer 8 start
th: 1       0ms Consumer 7 start
th: 5       0ms Consumer 4 start
th: 2       0ms Producer start
th: 6       0ms Consumer 5 start
th: 2       0ms Consumer 1 handling "foo2"
th: 6       0ms Consumer 2 handling "foo3"
th: 3       0ms Consumer 8 handling "bar2"
th: 7       0ms Consumer 6 start
th: 4       1ms Consumer 7 handling "bar3"
th: 4       1ms Consumer 4 handling "qux1"
th: 7       1ms Consumer 5 handling "qux2"
th: 4       1ms Producer signal system shutdown
th: 5       0ms Consumer 3 handling "bar1"
th: 8       0ms Consumer 9 start
th: 1       0ms Consumer 0 handling "foo1"
th: 4       1ms Producer leave
th: 3       1ms Consumer 9 leave (End of file)
th: 2       1ms Consumer 6 handling "qux3"
th: 8      11ms Consumer 7 leave (Channel closed)
th: 6      11ms Consumer 2 leave (Channel closed)
th: 5      11ms Consumer 4 leave (Channel closed)
th: 7      11ms Consumer 5 leave (Channel closed)
th: 3      11ms Consumer 3 leave (Channel closed)
th: 1      11ms Consumer 0 leave (Channel closed)
th: 8      11ms Consumer 8 leave (Channel closed)
th: 4      11ms Consumer 6 leave (Channel closed)
th: 2      11ms Consumer 1 leave (Channel closed)
```

Comment: Channels!  I did look at channels for a [previous software module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77788526/how-to-use-asio-concurrent-channel-with-multiple-signatures-c-20-coroutines), and I appreciate your answer there too.  The asio channel examples were clever, but they still seemed a little bleeding-edge, and the way control passed back and forth multiple times on each message was dizzying. But maybe it's time to consider them here.

Comment: Added examples both with sync (blocking) producer and with async producer. I think you're right that if there's no buffer space consumer and producer get "tangled" - interspersed - which may affect your throughput (but I think is actually a feature: it makes it possible for you to progress separate state machines "in lock-step" which is really a nifty feature at times). Therefore tune your parameters accordingly.

Comment: Oh, and late thought: consider the brand-new [Boost Cobalt library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/cobalt/doc/html/index.html) which has channels, but a host of other primitives (tasks, promises, etc.) without requiring Asio, but interoperating with it https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/cobalt/doc/html/index.html#motivation

Comment: Thanks for tip on strands, too!  Doing an `asio::post()` on the `io_context` from other threads: that's exactly the conceptual queueing equivalent to this. Might be an extra hand-off of each message -- or maybe not if I rework the receiver a little.

Lots of great ideas here. Thanks!

(Noted media v. transport.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Boost Cobalt too.  With co_await and co_return being language features, but asio and now cobalt being libraries, it's pretty confusing sorting it all out; what to expect from the compiler, standard libs, 3rd-party.  Maybe these two libraries span all the tools one would need. Otherwise, a complete list of tools & language features would be very cool.